# Nexus one hack to work on 8500/1900 freqs

Tags: nexus-one, 3g

I have a nexus one that (by default) does not support 8500/19000 3g frequencies.

That forces me to use EDGE or lower with my carrier.

The question is: Is this something that can be modified or is it a hardware limitation?

```
Note that I don't mind rooting the phone to get 3g support
```

Answer (score 4):

This is set in hardware, there is nothing you can do about this. You can learn more about this in http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=395c29e6b9cab6bc&hl=en